# Is there a way to hide all Offer stories on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

My stream recently started flooding with stories like "Your friend just claimed an offer from Sears, bla bla bla".

I don't see any way to collectively hide all Offer stories. Is there?

[image]

Comment: There should be. What do you see if you click on the "v" icon at the top right of the story in your feed?

Comment: @ChrisF - I get options to unsubscribe from my friend, or from "activity stories by my friend". Nothing that globally disables offers. Also, I'm not sure whether "activity stories" == offers, or are there other activities that are not offers.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot?

Comment: @ChrisF - done. I've crossed out the name of my friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to hide all Offer Stories (other than a user-script that targets the content) in the same way there is no way to hide all ads. Think of "Offers" as ads in plain sight.

Answer (score 1):

if you install the [FB Purity](http://fbpurity.com) browser extension, it will block all offer stories, along with sponsored stories, and any other story types you don’t want to see.